# Unable to load tor with Apache

Tags: php, apache, tor

I need to use a function to start and stop Tor via web interface. For some reason the following instruction doesn't work (no Tor process was spawned):

```
if ($_GET['tor'] == 'start') {
    shell_exec('/usr/bin/tor > /dev/null 2>&1 &');
...
```

But it works when I run the exact same string via shell:

```
$ php -r "shell_exec('killall tor > /dev/null 2>&1 &');"
```

How to solve the problem?

Thanks in advance.
K

---

The problem was related with /var/tor directory permissions. Since its being spawned by apache user, which doesn't have any home/.tor, he tries to create var/tor.
I was only able to get tor's output when starting tor using python (os.system("tor")).

Comment: Do you have sufficient permissions to run tor using this PHP script?

Comment: tor's permission are 755 (-rwxr-xr-x)

Comment: when I try to exec the php script via shell I'm not using root account. Shouldn't I get an access denied error in the error_log if the problem were permissions?

Comment: no because tor can be executed by OTH (-....-..-x), this script should work fine.

Comment: try running this as a PHP script: `$res = \`echo "test text" > test\`;` now can you see the `test` file and it's contents inside the wd your script resides?

Comment: error_log: sh: test: Permission denied

Comment: edit shell_exec line to be `$output = shell_exec('/usr/bin/tor > /dev/null 2>&1 &');` then `echo $output;` what does it show?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tor needs write permission to the home directory of the user running tor. This is often not the case for the user running the PHP script.

Try the echo $output; approach mentioned above. You might see this line:

```
[warn] Failed to parse/validate config: Couldn't access/create private data directory "/var/www/.tor"
```

Also make sure the path to Tor really is **/usr/bin/tor** on your system and not **/usr/sbin/tor**

Answer (score 0):

Are you running the php command as root? Because TOR might need to have root permissions to run. What output does shell_exec return?

Another thing is that I would suggest making use of php and ssh, this would allow you to install your scripts on another server while maintaining the functionality.

This tutorial should help you out nicely: http://kevin.vanzonneveld.net/techblog/article/make_ssh_connections_with_php/

Comment: Regarding the shell_exec return I get none. I'm checking for open port 9050 with netstat.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a permission issue,

```
chmod 777 /usr/bin/tor
```

But if this is open to the public, this may not be a great solution.

Comment: then tor must not be located there